# Three operator causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, exception, operator-keyword

I know, I could simply use abs in this case, but I'm just curious: why is this happening?

```
public float maxThrotle{
    set { maxThrotle = value < 0 ? -value : value;    //this line causes problem
    }
    get { return maxThrotle; }
}
```

Comment: Your setter assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your setter that assigns the maxThrotle property... Kaboom!

Comment: Your getter reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which runs your getter which reads the maxThrotle property.  Which .. Kaboom!

Comment: You are repeating yourself Hans. Getting old? ;)

Comment: fyi: the "?:" operator is usually called conditional (ternary) operator and it's quite impossible to cause a stackoverflow with it unless you have a condition which is evaluated recursively.

Comment: @garglblarg or one of the branches... consider what happens when you accidentally pass `i = 0` to `int f(int i) { return (i % 2 == 0) ? g(i) : h(i); }` where `g(i)` eventually calls `f(i)` at some point.

Comment: @CompuChip good point, i should have just mentioned recursion generally. but still not caused by the operator though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are causing an infinite loop, by trying to call the property setter from within the property setter.

You probably want to create a private backing field to store the value, as follows:

```
private float maxThrotle;
public float MaxThrotle {
    set { maxThrotle = value < 0 ? -value : value;    //this line causes problem
    }
    get { return maxThrotle; }
}
```

Note I renamed the property to use a capital letter, in accordance with most C# coding standards.

(Also, the word *throttle* is spelled with double -t-).

Comment: Ahww, that's so embarrassing!
Anyway, thank you for your reply. My programming teacher told me that in newest version of c# you don't need to implement additional private variable... but either he was wrong or i've misunderstood him.

Comment: If you don't need special logic in the getter and the setter, you can just write `public float MaxThrottle { get; set; }` which is equivalent to `private float _#maxThrottle; public float MaxThrottle { get { return _#maxThrottle; } set { _#maxThrottle = value; } }` (the compiler generates a backing field `_#maxThrottle` with an otherwise invalid name so you cannot access it except through the property). If you implement a custom getter and setter, though, you also need to implement the backing field.